# How can save help document to a file?

Tags: help-system

In vim `:h UltiSnips-python` in ex-mode can display all info on python usage in UltiSnips.
I want to save all the output as `/tmp/vim.output`.

```
:redir > /tmp/vim.output | :h UltiSnips-python   | redir END
```

It can't work,how can fix then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help` command opens a text file and `redir` command can not do anything about it.

Vim's help is just a collection of txt files located in respected `doc/` folders. You can either navigate there and do whatever needed with the file itself (copy to `/tmp/vim.output`) or you can use `:w` command to write help buffer contents to some other file:

[image: asciicast]